# ReactJS - How to populate individual entity data while we have the data available in state

Tags: reactjs

I am self learning ReactJS. I have a component like below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        let thedata = response.data;
        this.setState({ users: thedata });
        console.log(thedata);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    alert("You selected User with ID :: " + event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <strong>Select A User : </strong>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="" defaultValue>
            -SELECT-
          </option>
          {this.state.users.map((user) => (
            <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
              {user.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <p>????????????</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonList;
```

What I am trying to do is, when I select (that means onChange) the dropdown, I want to display the details of that user right below the dropdown. I am trying to avoid to write a separate component for the same functionality where I will make another rest call to get each individual user's details.

But at the same time, I am feeling lost as I am clueless on - should I do here in my `<p>` tag (in the reder method) to display the selected user's details.

Comment: I guess you want to store the selected user id in state?

Comment: Nope. I was thinking since I have all the users and their details in the current state, why I should go extra mile? Kindly suggest.

Comment: You have the list of users, but you need to store the value of the dropdown or else you won't know which user's data to display.

Comment: Ok. If I understood correctly, I need to create a separate component for this then? And use that here inside <p> tag?

Comment: you don't need a separate component, just add a piece of state called `selectedUserId` or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    try this if i understood it right 
    
    
    
    class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    selectedUser: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ users: res });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedUser: this.state.users.find(item => item.id == event.target.value) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <strong>Select A User : </strong>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
          {this.state.users &&
            this.state.users.map(user => (
              <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>
                {user.name}
              </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        <p>{this.state.selectedUser.name}</p>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonList;
```

Comment: pretty close what I am looking for but just wondering how do i get all the details instead of just name? other details like email, username, address, phone etc?

Comment: just remove ?.name from <p>{this.state.users.find(item => item.id == this.state.selectedUserId)?.name}</p> and pick any key that you need from selected option in array

Comment: console.log(this.state.users.find(item => item.id == this.state.selectedUserId))  check it in render and you'll see

Comment: changed set selected user check now

Comment: still I am getting just name only or your mean to say - <p>{this.state.selectedUser.name}</p>
        <p>{this.state.selectedUser.id}</p>
        <p>{this.state.selectedUser.email}</p>
        <p>{this.state.selectedUser.phone}</p>  ??

Comment: yea pick just other key like that

Comment: Got it. It looks ugly approach :-) but I asked for it. :-) For now I got enough food for thoughts. Thanks a bunch @Bogden for your time and effort.

Comment: yea it's just simplest way for now)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected  user in the state and in order to display user details, you will need to display a list of information using for example:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";

class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    selectedUser: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        let thedata = response.data;
        this.setState({ users: thedata });
        console.log(thedata);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    setState({selectedUser: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    let user = null
    const {selectedUser} = this.state
    if(selecteduser) {
          user = (<p>User id: {selecteduser.id}</p><br/><p>name: {selectedUser.name}</>)
    }
    return (
      <>
        <strong>Select A User : </strong>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="" defaultValue>
            -SELECT-
          </option>
          {this.state.users.map((user) => (
            <option key={user.id} value={user}> //change user.id to user
              {user.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        {user}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default PersonList;
```

And if you want to write clean code, you can create a component called UserDetails taking user as a prop .

Comment: Sure will accomplish by using a separate component as I was thinking earlier, but for now I was looking for a dirty solution and got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I dont know why u prefered the first answer, this call  this.state.users.find(item => item.id == event.target.value) is useless you change value=user.id to value=user, and directly set your user.